# Retrieve rows where their stored time frame has one or more occurrences of a given week day

Tags: mysql, innodb

I would like to know the best way  (performance) to retrieve rows from a MySQL table, where two date type fields, who together compose a given time frame, happen to have a certain week day somewhere among the time frame in question.

Assuming the given table structure and data example, what would be the best way of retrieving all rows where their stored time frame happens to have one or more occurrences of Monday for example, where Monday is referenced by the number 2.

```
Table: ExampleA
Fields:
ID (int) | Begin (date) | End (date)
------------------------------------
1        |  2012-02-14  | 2012-02-16
2        |  2012-01-01  | 2012-01-15
3        |  2012-03-04  | 2012-03-06
4        |  2012-01-23  | 2012-02-07
5        |  2012-07-15  | 2012-07-15
6        |  2012-03-06  | 2012-03-13
```

In example query it would be preferred to reference the given week day by a non-zero based index, starting from Sunday ending on Saturday, composing the following index positions: 1 to 7 respectively. (Same as the MySQL function [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).)

**UPDATE:**

Been looking over some way on how to iterate day by day through a given time frame and doesn't look good. The requirement to create Temporary tables and such, not practical and when simultaneous users request a action with the same requirement it would cause problems.

Example: [How can I get a list of dates between two given dates with mysql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8155/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-given-dates-with-mysql)

The initial idea was to loop through each day of the time frame of each row. Then for each time frame go through the initial date to the end date day by day and return a list of which week days were found for each time frame (row). Not a fast way for sure, but just something to get started. Any recommendations or other suggestions better than this one?

**UPDATE 2:**

[G-Nugget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621209/g-nugget) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283551/114298) creating seven boolean fields one for each week day, and when adding a new row, mark the appropriate fields true for the week days found in the time frame of said row. Of course this being done by the application using the database, not the SQL query itself.

It is the most straightforward and least performance impacting solution I've though or seen to this time, however I cannot edit the table schema.

**UPDATE 3:**

To clarify this question even more, in the event someone is confused or misreads it. Note:

> I'm looking to retrieve the rows where you can find the week day
>   Monday or another week day of my choosing somewhere in their time
>   frame (going from "Being" to "End"), either at the "Begin", "End", or along the period of time
>   ranging from "Begin" to "End"

**UPDATE 4:**

Here you have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74de7/8/0) of this question for you to try your ideas, without having to build the table in your machine.

**UPDATE 5 - Solution:**

Using [Alexey Gerasimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029908/alexey-gerasimov) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284165/114298) I was able to apply his where clause logic to my own problem and work through my solution. Thanks Alexey.

If your reading this and want to try it and see if it suits your needs:

You can use this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74de7/14/1) or this small query to setup and run his solution:

```
# Create table
CREATE TABLE `ExampleA` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Begin` date NOT NULL,
  `End` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

# Insert demo data
INSERT INTO `ExampleA`(`ID`,`Begin`,`End`) VALUES  
(1,'2012-02-14','2012-02-16'),
(2,'2012-01-01','2012-01-15'),
(3,'2012-03-04','2012-03-06'),
(4,'2012-01-23','2012-02-07'),
(5,'2012-07-15','2012-07-15'),
(6,'2012-03-06','2012-03-13');

# Query to retrieve rows which time frame
# has one or more occurrences of a given weekday
#
# 1 Sunday
# 2 Monday
# 3 Tuesday
# 4 Wednesday
# 5 Thursday 
# 6 Friday
# 7 Saturday

SET @MYDAYOFWEEK=2;
SELECT * FROM ExampleA
WHERE
(
        ( @MYDAYOFWEEK >= DAYOFWEEK(BEGIN) AND @MYDAYOFWEEK <= DAYOFWEEK(BEGIN) + DATEDIFF(END,BEGIN) )
    OR  
        ( 
          @MYDAYOFWEEK+7 >= DAYOFWEEK(BEGIN) AND @MYDAYOFWEEK+7 <= DAYOFWEEK(BEGIN) + DATEDIFF(END,BEGIN) 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
select * from ExampleA
where ID = MYDAYOFWEEK
and (
        ( id >= dayofweek(begin) and id <= dayofweek(begin) + DATEDIFF(end,begin) )
    OR  
        ( 
        id+7 >= dayofweek(begin) and id+7 <= dayofweek(begin) + DATEDIFF(end,begin) 
        )
    )
```

first check matches the days in the same week, second takes care of weeks spanning. Not sure if this is the best performing query though

**UPDATE**

Sorry. I thought the first column is date of the week. To fix, simply change the query as below:

```
select * from ExampleA
where (
        ( MYDAYOFWEEK >= dayofweek(begin) and MYDAYOFWEEK <= dayofweek(begin) + DATEDIFF(end,begin) )
    OR  
        ( 
        MYDAYOFWEEK+7 >= dayofweek(begin) and MYDAYOFWEEK+7 <= dayofweek(begin) + DATEDIFF(end,begin) 
        )
    )
```

This one is definitely NOT speedy

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alexey, you should note the day of the week is not stored in the "ID" field on the table. The "ID" field is just for clarity and commonality sake. In any way can it be used to find what day or days of the week are present in the time frame, time frame of which is determined by the "begin" and "end" fields.

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Comment: I've added few more rows, to test every individual week day. Then I've implemented your solution to the real table, and wrote a small code on the application side, just to test the results the database returned, and all came true positives, your where clause works well on over 2000 rows with varying time frames. Sorry for my mistake earlier, guess I wasn't reading my results with your query properly. (I will remove all my erroneous comments regarding my mistake, so people won't be confused in the future when reading this)  Thank you. Ohh by the way the query has a good performance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "good" way to do what you're asking with how your data is currently set up.  An index cannot be used in this query since you cannot know which days are in the range until you read the two dates.

One possible way to improve the performance of the query would be to have an indicator field (something like `TINYINT` or `CHAR(1)`) for each day.  It *could* help, but, in general, it might actually slow down the table due to the increased size and indexes.  If you would only need to know if something happened on one or two days, this option could work, but the extra size would probably outweigh the benefits if you needed more than 2 or 3 days.

Comment: Adding another column as you say isn't a good option, because as you can see I'm working with two dates which compose a given time frame that might have only one week day, or have all 7 week days.

Comment: @FábioAntunes You're right, I overlooked that.  I'm editing my answer with a different possible solution.

Comment: On your update, if I understood you correctly, you suggest creating seven additional boolean fields tinyint(1) one for each week day, and when a row is added to the table, the adding query or application code, would have the responsibility of marking true the additional boolean fields corresponding to the appropriate week days found in the time frame in question.
Correct? If so, then it would surely solve the problem, with the least performance impact possible for what I've seen and thought so far, however I do not have the privilege to edit the current database structure.

Comment: @FábioAntunes Yeah, for my updated solution, you'd need to modify the structure.  One thing I was looking into but didn't pan out is using a `BIT` field, but MySQL doesn't index those in a way that would help here.

Comment: I like you approach, but unfortunately I cannot edit the table schema. If you have any other ideas I would appreciate it.